# Disable automatic printer recognition on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, hp, samsung

Helo Everyone,

Everytime I connect to the network, Cups installs all the printers in the network automatically, some more than once.

Furthermore, I connect a USB printer to the laptop every now and then. Even though the printer is configured already, another printer is added to the list.

I wish to disable this feature and allow only manual installation of printers. How do I go about it?

Comment: https://cirovladimir.wordpress.com/2019/02/11/ubuntu-18-04-disable-network-printer-auto-discovery/ The link is for 18.04 but I don't see a reaon not for it to work on 19.10